# How to use the update after create form in yii2?

Tags: php, sql, yii2

I have a `_form`:

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'result')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'test1')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'test2')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

<?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Update', ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
```

I need to set a formula: **result = test1*test2**

Using raw sql I can put it in controller:

```
public function actionIndex(){
     Yii::$app->db->createCommand("UPDATE table1 SET result = test1*test2")->execute();
etc...
}
```

And it's ok. But I think it's not correct. So the best way to do this is:

```
       public function actionTest($id)
       {
            $model = $this->findModel($id);
            $model->result = $model->test1 * model->test2 
       }
```

after:

```
<?= Html::a('gotest', ['test', 'id' => $model->id], ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
```

But how can I get `$model->id` from form create to actionIndex ? Or maybe other option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a clean way to do this in Yii2 should be using `afterFind` callback to fill your `result` field with your calculated value, like this:

In your **Model**:

```
public function afterFind()
{
    $this->result = $this->test1 * $this->test2;
}
```

All logic you put in your `afterFind` will be executed just after Yii2 get the result from DB. It's nice when you need to calculate something before put in a form or a DataProvider, because everything will happens right in the model.

If I get this right, you won't even need the result field in your database. (in this way, just declare it in your model, creating an virtual field like this: `public $result;` and you'll be able to use it just like if it exists in table.

Comment: In this case, I need result in database. And `afterFind()` workes very nice, I tested a minute ago. And to add virtual field with `public $result;` very interesting, I think it will be required for another task. Virtual fileds I use to get Array from for ex. `checkboxList()` and inserting into a database cell(using `implode`). So your answer wiil improve my understanding about using model. Thank you a lot